# OnePlus (Android 10) - Main screen freezes when on PIP Mode

Tags: android, android-10.0, android-picture-in-picture, oneplus6t

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
android:supportsPictureInPicture="true"
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:configChanges="screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout"
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden"
android:parentActivityName=".activity.MyDriefCaseMenu"
android:resizeableActivity="true"
android:autoRemoveFromRecents="true"
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
android:allowTaskReparenting="true"
```

Above are the attributes of the activity in manifest. The PIP mode does not allow me to do other task in my app. The screen freezes. This is on OnePlus 6t only

Comment: Bro did you get the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your Manifest looks good Bro.

I will suggest you to add one more activity attribute in manifest (If you are using multi activity architecture)

```
android:taskAffinity="pipFeature"
```

This will keep your PIP activity in **different stack**. Thus the behaviour will be different than other activities of application.

2nd most important thing to fix your issue is -
Since you are using OnePlus 6T (Your question dated 22nd April) you might be having Android 10 OS (API level 29).

Just checking in your gradle whether you targeted API level 29 or not. If you have targetSdkVersion below 29 (Android 10) then PIP feature will behave weird just like you said freezes the screen when pressed back.

So,

```
targetSdkVersion 29
```

or above is must.

I know I am late answering this but this might help others. I was also having same issue while working on old project which I solved with above given solution.